# Alternative to "X and I's Y"

Tags: grammaticality

I'm looking for an alternative to expressions of the form "X and I's Y", where X is a person/group and Y is a noun. Examples include:

1. My partner and I's project was well-received.
2. My family and I's trip went well.

I'm not even sure if the above two sentences are gramatically correct, but even if they are, they sound awful. What's a better way to say these sentences?

Comment: The possessive of the pronoun *I* is *my*, not *I's*.

Comment: @deadrat So could I say "My partner and my project was well-received?"

Comment: No, that sentence means that your partner was well-received and your project was well-received. You'll need to say, "My partner's and my project was well-received. "

Comment: "My and my partner's project" would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it would be "my partner's and my". It still makes sense if you remove "my partner's and" or "and my".

Comment: But "John and Bill's cars", which is equally grammatical, and is used to show joint ownership, fails that test (though "John's and Bill's cars", again grammatical, passes).

Comment: We appreciate the desire to help, but please consider either expanding your answer or deleting it. We're looking for long answers that provide explanation and context. Explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Unsupported answers may be removed. [(more¹)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post) [(more²)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166566/lots-of-not-always-useful-but-well-intentioned-answers)